# Core data persistent store coordinator isnt present

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

im going through the Apple Doc's tutorial for the [Core Data Tutorial for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/03_ManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH102-SW1) and when i press the `+` button to add an event to my tableView, the app crashes and the console states: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'` I have went through the tutorial many times and i cannot find anywhere that the tutorial says anything about the store. So is there code I'm supposed to add that it isn't showing?

Answer (score 2):

You must have forgotten to add a persistent store. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:) for how to create a persistent store.

---

#### Edit

After creating the persistent store, follow it up with a call like this:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = /* Assume this exists */;
NSURL *storeURL = /* ... */;

[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSSQLiteStoreType
                                         configuration: nil
                                                   URL: storeURL
                                               options: nil
                                                 error: NULL];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you help me with this? Ive never done it before!! Thanks again! :D, it doesnt say how to do this in the core data tutorial!

Comment: Could you please assist me with adding the persistent store? You gave me a link to the method header. I'm not sure what to type within the body of the method! Thanks

Comment: Hope that helps. Don't forget to use your own PSC and to supply your own store URL. :)

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers I got this error:NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter

Comment: @Coder101 That probably deserves a separate SO question.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new project using Xcode's Master-Detail template, selecting "use Core Data" to get a current working example. Once you have a working project in front of you, search the project for NSPersistentStoreCoordinator - it is much easier to understand the docs in conjunction with a working code example than it is to understand them while trying to create working code from nothing.

Comment: Hey, i still cannot get this tutorial to work, and i've created the master-detail app and i cannot follow along! Because they use a FetchedResultsController and it's totally different than the tutorial! please help!